# How do I get my cards to fit my container?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a memory card game  based on the TV Show, The Sopranos with 20 cards.
I've got a few issues with my `css`.

I want my cards to fit my `section`. I'm using a `border` to experiment with different units but I can't seem to figure out what I've got to do to get my cards to fit my `section` container.

I've got **The rest of the cards in a 4 column grid after each soprano card div**

```
<section class ="soprano-game"
<div class="soprano-card">
            <img class="front-card" src="assets/img/Characters/Tony-Soprano.jpg" alt="Characters">
            <img class="back-card" src="assets/img/Sopranos-Title.jpg" alt="Sopranos-Title">
        </div>
</section>

.soprano-game {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 150vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 150px);
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid purple;
}
.soprano-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}

.front-card,
.back-card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

It would mean a lot if someone could explain to how I can fit my card divs into my section regardless of the height and width of the section

Comment: Could you show a slightly more complete HTML? With say two soprano cards each with their other cards as I can't quite make out what you mean. Also I guess you know there is a missing bracket after the section?

Comment: No I didn't see it initially, thanks for letting me know. 
I've solved the problem, I had to create an inner div as a container as my cards weren't flipping. Thanks for your input